# Finding the Nodes of an Edge in LEMON graph library

Tags: c++, graph, lemon-graph-library

Suppose that I have an Edge. How can I easily find which two nodes it connects? The documentation of LEMON is so sparse, I could not find info on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use source and target to find the nodes an edge connects, it works like this

```
ListDigraph graph;
ListDigraph::Arc edge;
ListDigraph::Node a1,a2;
a1 = graph.source(edge);
a2 = graph.target(edge);
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought the edge itself could tell its endpoints, but turns out I need the graph.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is wondering how to achieve this in the **undirected** setting (to which an "edge" is supposed to refer, as opposed to an "arc" in the directed setting) , the corresponding methods to `source` and `target` are `u` and `v`. A snippet for listing the endpoints of all edges of an undirected graph `G` would look something like this:

```
for(ListGraph::EdgeIt edge(G); edge != INVALID; ++edge) 
    std::cout << G.id(G.u(edge)) << " -- " << G.id(G.v(edge)) << endl;
```

See [the relevant part of LEMON's documentation](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/pub/tutorial/a00023.html).